# Website data retrieval

Tags: api, data-retrieval

An recent [article](http://www.sdtimes.com/link/33578) has prompted me to pick up a project I have been working on for a while.  I want to create a web service front end for a number of sites to allow automated completion of forms and data retrieval from the results, and other areas of the site.  I have acheived a degree of success using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and custom code however I am looking to extend this to a stage where adding additional sites is a trivial task (maybe one which doesn't require a developer even).

The [Kapow web data server](http://kapowtech.com/index.php/products/kapow-web-data-server) looks to achieve a lot of this however I am told it is quite expensive (currently awaiting a quote).  Has anyone had experience with this, or can suggest any alternatives (Open Source ideally)?

**Disclaimer:** I realise the potential legality issues around automating data retrieval from 3rd party websites - this tool is designed to be used in a price comparison system and all of the websites integrated with it will be done with the express permission of the owners.  Where the sites provide an API this will clearly be the favoured approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised it's been a while since I posted this, however should anyone come across it, I have had lots of success in using the [WSO2](http://wso2.com/) framework (particularly the mashup server) for this.  For data mining tasks I have also used a Java library that this wraps - webharvest - which has achieved everything I needed